# Preserving Sandbox Changes During Refresh

Tags: change-set

We are refreshing our sandbox and I've been working on a build that is not ready to be deployed into production. In order to preserve the changes during the sandbox refresh, I was going to put everything into a change set for Production, wait for the sandbox to refresh, then deploy the change set back to sanbox to continue iterating.

Would this be best practice? Do I need to do anything specific like 'validate' the change set in production to preserve the change set?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An inbound change set cannot then be used as an outbound change set. Instead, consider cloning the sandbox into another sandbox, then refresh the original, then you can use a change set to deploy any changes back to the original sandbox after refresh.

Comment: The sandbox I'm working in is a full sandbox and we can't clone it due to licenses. Do you recommend I deploy the change set into a different sandbox, then remake and outbound change set to deploy back to full?

Comment: @Nivi That would be an acceptable alternative. The main point is that you can't just leave the change set in production while you refresh. Alternatively, if you moved to DX, you could use unlocked packages and/or a repo to store the changes.

Comment: If understand correctly, however, I can't deploy a sandbox to another sandbox. I have to push to production, then push to the new sandbox. Do I have to deploy/validate in production in order to deploy that change set to the new sandbox?

Comment: @Nivi no, you can deploy between sandboxes using change sets. You simply have to set up a deployment connection between the two (found in setup). You do not need to go through production, nor do you need to validate. If you try to go through production, you would be forced to deploy the new features before you could create a new change set to push to the sandbox, which is presumably not your intent.

Comment: got it. I enabled 'inbound change sets' for the sandbox I want to push to (it's a Dev Pro). However, I'm still only seeing 'Production' and our partial sandbox. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Nivi you also have to enable the outbound connection.

Comment: Ah, okay. 'Accept Outbound Change Sets' is grayed out for some reason, and won't let me select.